# Xcode Crash due to Persistance container in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently making an app implementing core data. However, when I build, it crashes at this line:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unresolved error Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "Persistent store migration
>   failed, missing mapping model."
>   UserInfo={sourceModel=() isEditable
>   0, entities {

What does this mean? How can I solve this?

Comment: You have made some changes to your core data model and you haven't provided information on how to map the old model to the new one.  If you don't care about the existing data the simplest solution is to delete the app from your device or simulator before running it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe the solution only took a couple of seconds to do!