# assign jpegData to binary core data

Tags: swift, image, core-data, binary-data, assign

My swift code below is trying to save a image litteral to binary core data pic. A image litteral is a image located locally within the xcode project.  I am getting a complie error at object.pic = newUser stating Cannot assign value of type 'User' to type 'Data?'. User is the name of my core Data Model. When the code loads it should just save the image literal to the Xcode project. This is a link to gitHub https://github.com/redrock34/lebron.

```
    import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {


let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

lazy var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let newUser = User(context: context)

    newUser.pic = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Jessica").jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9) as NSObject? as! Data


    setValue(newUser, forKey: "pic")


    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("\(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }




}}
```

[image]

Comment: From your code, you are already created object of User and assign image data to pic then why are you creating another object for User?

Comment: your right do not need that deleted that line.

Comment: You are also assigning image data to newUser.pic then what is use of this line `newUser.pic = newUser` in your code? and try to print `newUser`

Comment: I am trying to convert image to uiimage then save it as binary data.

Comment: Edited my code above now getting a error added a pic above as well. Thanks for you help so far.

Comment: Can you add whole error message and on which line it gives error in your code?

Comment: I added a photo above with the debug section. When the app builds it crashes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Try to check:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155241/xcode-crash-due-to-persistance-container-in-swift for your error

Comment: Please **read** what you are doing. You create a new User and assign it to the `pic` attribute of another user. This cannot work. I told you a couple of times **not** to use generic `setValue(forKey)`. With dot notation you get a compiler error on a type mismatch. And you are discouraged from saving images in  Core Data locally anyway. Save the image with an UUID on disk separately and save only the URL in Core Data

Comment: @vadian I edited my code above your right I don't need to declare var ee. I am still getting the error. Can you just tell me what to code? It has to be close.

Comment: @KishanBhatiya  I edited my code above your right I don't need to declare var ee. I am still getting the error. Can you just tell me what to code? It has to be close.

Comment: You are still using discouraged `setValue(forKey`. Calling the method directly tries to save the image in a property `pic` of the view controller. This makes no sense either. Once again save the image on disk in a folder in `Documents` with an UUID and save only this UUID (file name) in Core Data.