# I'm getting this error that says migration failed in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

Here is the error I'm getting in Xcode. Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

```
file ShadowGovernanceApp/AppDelegate.swift, line 58
2021-12-07 13:47:09.367225+0100 ShadowGovernanceApp[42526:14643030] Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model." UserInfo={destinationModel=(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x600000bd6b70>) isEditable 0, entities {
    EmployeeDetails = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x600001ff0f20>) name EmployeeDetails, managedObjectClassName ShadowGovernanceApp.Employee, renamingIdentifier EmployeeDetails, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    capgBU = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d2a80>), name capgBU, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier capgBU, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    capgEmail = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d3a00>), name capgEmail, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier capgEmail, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    capgID = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d2d80>), name capgID, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier capgID, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    mentorName = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d2c80>), name mentorName, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier mentorName, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    name = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d2e00>), name name, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    projectName = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d3700>), name projectName, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier projectName, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    taskDescription = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d3600>), name taskDescription, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier taskDescription, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
}, sourceModel=(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x600000bd7160>) isEditable 0, entities {
    EmployeeDetails = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x600001ff2050>) name EmployeeDetails, managedObjectClassName ShadowGovernanceApp.Employee, renamingIdentifier EmployeeDetails, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    capgBU = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9100>), name capgBU, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier capgBU, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    capgEmail = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9300>), name capgEmail, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier capgEmail, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    capgID = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9200>), name capgID, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier capgID, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 300 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    mentorName = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9480>), name mentorName, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier mentorName, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    name = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9400>), name name, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    projectName = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9380>), name projectName, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier projectName, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    taskDescription = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9280>), name taskDescription, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier taskDescription, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
}, reason=Can't find mapping model for migration}, ["destinationModel": (<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x600000bd6b70>) isEditable 0, entities {
    EmployeeDetails = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x600001ff0f20>) name EmployeeDetails, managedObjectClassName ShadowGovernanceApp.Employee, renamingIdentifier EmployeeDetails, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    capgBU = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d2a80>), name capgBU, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier capgBU, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    capgEmail = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d3a00>), name capgEmail, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier capgEmail, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    capgID = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d2d80>), name capgID, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier capgID, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    mentorName = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d2c80>), name mentorName, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier mentorName, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    name = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d2e00>), name name, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    projectName = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d3700>), name projectName, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier projectName, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    taskDescription = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006d3600>), name taskDescription, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier taskDescription, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
}, "reason": Can't find mapping model for migration, "sourceModel": (<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x600000bd7160>) isEditable 0, entities {
    EmployeeDetails = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x600001ff2050>) name EmployeeDetails, managedObjectClassName ShadowGovernanceApp.Employee, renamingIdentifier EmployeeDetails, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    capgBU = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9100>), name capgBU, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier capgBU, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    capgEmail = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9300>), name capgEmail, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier capgEmail, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    capgID = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9200>), name capgID, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier capgID, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 300 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    mentorName = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9480>), name mentorName, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier mentorName, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    name = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9400>), name name, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    projectName = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9380>), name projectName, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier projectName, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    taskDescription = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x6000006c9280>), name taskDescription, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity EmployeeDetails, renamingIdentifier taskDescription, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
}]: file ShadowGovernanceApp/AppDelegate.swift, line 58
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155241/xcode-crash-due-to-persistance-container-in-swift You need to look for the error `"Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model."`. You changed your CoreData Model, but didn't provide a way to tell your code how to go from previous version to new one. If it's a "debug", you can delete your app and redo it, starting from scratch, no migration needed. If not, it's up to you to know your changes and provide a migration mapping model.

Comment: uninstall you application and reinstall your application